# A question about posets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A lattice is defined as a partially ordered set $M$ such that for any two $x,y\in M$, there exists a greatest lower bound $x\vee y$.

Can $x\vee y$ have to be either $x$ or $y$? Or can it also be a third element outside of $\{x,y\}$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yest, both of those are possible.  One important poset on $\mathbb{N}$ is the gcd.

Comment: (@vadim "partial order on $\mathbb N$", or "poset is $\mathbb N$ with the gcd".)

Comment: I have a somewhat related question. Doed $\Bbb{R}$ not satisfy the condition that every ordered chain has an upper bound; $(0,\infty)$ for example? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

For example, consider the set of integers partially ordered by divisibility. Then $8∨12=4$, and $3∨6=3$.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is defined for posets (partially ordered sets) is exactly because you can define it in cases when neither $x<y$ nor $y<x$. In such cases, of course, $x\vee y$ is neither $x$ nor $y$.

In other words, yes, there exist lattices that are not (fully) ordered.

I think, you can even say this fact as a "result":

a lattice is ordered iff for any two $x$ and $y$: $x\vee y\in\{x,y\}$.